# How to query for a range of previous week (i.e. 14 days ago to 7 days ago)

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query, but I'm trying to pull this data for the week before this.  Is there a way to set a range between to points without referring to today or a set `datestamp`?

```
SELECT
  Count(orders.id) AS order_count
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  orders.requested_delivery_date between CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days' and now()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to parameterize your query so you can supply startdate and enddate at invocation time? If it's so, then I think you have to use user defined function for that. If not, maybe you could clarify your question.

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the query so that instead of returning orders from the last 7 days I could pull results from the previous week (orders with a datestamp of 14-8 days ago).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(orders.id) as order_count
from orders
where
    date_trunc('week', requested_delivery_date) =
    date_trunc('week', current_date - interval '7 days')
```